# Unable to show child view (iOS view container)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

In my iOS application, I have a main View Controller with three buttons, which work like a tab bar: when I click one of the buttons, a new view controller is invoked. 
I tried to implement this via container view containers, so I tried following this guide (http://www.thinkandbuild.it/working-with-custom-container-view-controllers/) and invoke the presentDetailController method in the viewDidLoad of the main controller.

Actually, no views are showed: someone can help me figuring out why? Thanks.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *detailView;

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property UIViewController  *currentDetailViewController;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithString:@"I'm the first Controller!"];

    [self presentDetailController:fvc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    // button selection stuff

    [self addDetailController:sender];
}

- (void)presentDetailController:(UIViewController*)detailVC{

    //0. Remove the current Detail View Controller showed
    if(self.currentDetailViewController){
        [self removeCurrentDetailViewController];
    }

    //1. Add the detail controller as child of the container
    [self addChildViewController:detailVC];

    //2. Define the detail controller's view size
    detailVC.view.frame = [self frameForDetailController];

    //3. Add the Detail controller's view to the Container's detail view and save a reference to the detail View Controller
    [self.detailView addSubview:detailVC.view];
    self.currentDetailViewController = detailVC;

    //4. Complete the add flow calling the function didMoveToParentViewController
    [detailVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}


- (void)removeCurrentDetailViewController{

    //1. Call the willMoveToParentViewController with nil
    //   This is the last method where your detailViewController can perform some operations before neing removed
    [self.currentDetailViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    //2. Remove the DetailViewController's view from the Container
    [self.currentDetailViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    //3. Update the hierarchy"
    //   Automatically the method didMoveToParentViewController: will be called on the detailViewController)
    [self.currentDetailViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}

- (CGRect)frameForDetailController{
    // newFrame's height should be currentFrame's height minus buttons' height

    CGRect detailFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.detailView.bounds.size.width, self.detailView.bounds.size.height-self.btnOne.frame.size.height);
    return detailFrame;
}

- (void)addDetailController:(id)sender {
    FirstViewController *detailVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithString:@"First button clicked"];

    [self presentDetailController:detailVC];

}




@end
```

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnThree;


- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)string;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController (){
    NSString *text;
}
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)string {
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        text = string;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label.text = text;

}


@end
```

[image: Main View Controller]
[image: First View Controller]

Comment: I don't see any major problem which can cause your views not to be shown. Just make sure all your outlets are linked properly. Its working fine at my end.

Comment: Checked once again, outlets are linked well... I really don't get it, thanks for your answer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of creating `FirstViewController`, you are calling `[super init]` which produces a bare `UIViewController`.  From your diagram, it seems as if you want to load a `FirstViewController` from your storyboard instead.

I suggest a sequence where you create your controller using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, then set a string property in the controller that you want to use as the label, and finally assign the string to the label when the controller's view loads.

Comment: Worked this way. Thanks!